# Using submit button and enter key to add to-do-list

Tags: javascript, css

I am doing a simple to-do list to keep learning JS and so far I have two issues that I can't solve, I would like to know if you guys could help me.

First, I would like to use the button and the enter key to add a task instead of just pressing enter, I know I could use a form and the preventDefault(); method but I would like to explore other options, I can make it work by changing the event listener to 'click' since the button is a submit type but then the text won't add when pressing enter.

Second, the "There are no pending tasks." message div shows up at the beginning when no tasks are added and disappear when a task is added, so far its ok but when I delete all the tasks the message won't show up again, maybe my logic is failing somehow but can't figure it out where.

```js
let board = document.querySelector('.to-do-board');
let taskContainer = document.querySelector('.container-task');
let taskbar = document.querySelector('.add-task');
let button = document.querySelector('.add-btn');
let noTasksMsg = document.querySelector('.message');


taskbar.addEventListener('keypress', (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && taskbar.value !== '') {
    
        if (taskContainer === null) {
            noTasksMsg.style.display = 'flex';
        } else {
            noTasksMsg.style.display = 'none';
        }

        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'item-task';
        div.innerHTML = taskbar.value;
        taskContainer.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', div)

        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
        deleteButton.className = 'deleteBtn';
        deleteButton.textContent = "X";
        div.appendChild(deleteButton);

        taskbar.value = '';

        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            div.remove();
        })
    }
})
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 15px;
}

.to-do-board {
    width: 500px;
    background: #88CCF1;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.title {
    background: #3587A4;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: .5em 0 .5em 0;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.inputs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 1em;
}

.add-task {
    padding: .5em;
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.add-btn {
    padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #2D848A;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.add-btn:hover {
    background: #3587A4;
}

.container-task {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1em;
}

.item-task {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #C1DFF0;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.deleteBtn {
    border: none;
    background: #d45151;
    width: 3em;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    height: 2.5em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.deleteBtn:hover {
    background: rgb(235, 95, 95);
}

.message {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background: #63afb1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <title>To-do List!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="to-do-board">
            <div class="title"><h1>To-Do List!</h1></div>
            <div class="inputs">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Add a task" class="add-task">
                <input type="submit" value="+" class="add-btn">
            </div>
            <div class="container-task">
                <div class="message">There are no pending tasks.</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: _"I would like to use the button and the enter key to add a task instead of just pressing enter"_ - what is that even supposed to mean? Hold down the enter key, and then press the button while doing so?

Comment: _"Second, the "There are no pending tasks." message div shows up at the beginning when no tasks are added"_ - but not due to anything in your scripting, it simply shows because it is in the HTML, and the stylesheet applies `display: flex;`. Your `if (taskContainer === null)` there makes little sense. Only way this could be null, is if the element did not exist at the time the line `let taskContainer = document.querySelector('.container-task');` executed.

Comment: @CBroe sorry, my english is still bad, I mean, I want to use both options, pressing enter so the text will be added and also, if the user wants, adding it by clicking the "+" button.

Sorry, about the taskContainer question, I did not understand it completely, so basically the if sentence is not needed?

Comment: Well then you will need to add a click handler for the button - because it won't fire any `keypress` events. (This is the place where actually using a form could have benefits, because forms _can_ be submitted by pressing enter inside a text input field as well. So you could do it using only _one_ submit handler then, instead of having to handle button click and keypress separately.)

Comment: `task container` will never be null. Hence, `noTaskMessage` will not be shown again. You should check for missing children and not the `task container` itself.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, I will find another method, since as you said, `taskContainer` will never be null.

@JohnYepthomi There is where I fail, looking for a missing children? Maybe I should just create a new div with JS when taskContainer doesn't containt any div? I am kind of lost here...

Thank you both.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the code inside your `eventListener` to a separate function, pass it the event object and slightly modify it to check if `e.type` is `click` in addition to checking for the *enter* key but I'd still recommend against it and recommend using `<form>`.

```js
let board = document.querySelector('.to-do-board');
let taskContainer = document.querySelector('.container-task');
let taskbar = document.querySelector('.add-task');
let button = document.querySelector('.add-btn');


taskbar.addEventListener('keypress', handleEvent)
button.addEventListener('click', handleEvent)

function handleEvent(e){
   if ((e.type === 'click' || e.key === 'Enter') && taskbar.value !== '') {

        if(taskContainer.querySelector(".message") != null){
            taskContainer.querySelector(".message").remove()
        }
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'item-task';
        div.innerHTML = taskbar.value;
        taskContainer.appendChild(div)

        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button')
        deleteButton.className = 'deleteBtn';
        deleteButton.textContent = "X";
        div.appendChild(deleteButton);

        taskbar.value = '';

        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            div.remove();
            if(taskContainer.children.length == 0){
                const message = document.createElement("div")
                message.classList.add("message")
                message.textContent = "There are no pending tasks."
                taskContainer.appendChild(message);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
  }

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 15px;
}

.to-do-board {
    width: 500px;
    background: #88CCF1;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.title {
    background: #3587A4;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    padding: .5em 0 .5em 0;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.inputs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 1em;
}

.add-task {
    padding: .5em;
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.add-btn {
    padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #2D848A;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.add-btn:hover {
    background: #3587A4;
}

.container-task {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1em;
}

.item-task {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: #C1DFF0;
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.deleteBtn {
    border: none;
    background: #d45151;
    width: 3em;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    height: 2.5em;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.deleteBtn:hover {
    background: rgb(235, 95, 95);
}

.message {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background: #63afb1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" lang="en">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    <title>To-do List!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="to-do-board">
            <div class="title"><h1>To-Do List!</h1></div>
            <div class="inputs">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Add a task" class="add-task">
                <input type="submit" value="+" class="add-btn">
            </div>
            <div class="container-task">
               <div class="message">
                  You have not added any tasks.
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Again, `task container` will never be null. Hence, `noTaskMessage` will not be shown again. You should check for missing children and not the `task container` itself. This was also part of the issue that OP asked for.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that part of the question, just modified my answer.

Comment: Now I get it... thank you!!